I am confused why I failed this audit
I received this audit in the First Answers queue:
https://superuser.com/review/first-answers/1243942
I am sure I downvoted the post, and it has in fact been deleted. So why did I fail it?

Which action did you select?  The only action that would have not resulted in failing the audit would have been casting a downvote and selecting "other action".  Sharing Feedback (a comment), editing, or selecting "looks ok" on deleted content would have resulted in failing audit.
